# Why is it that when I set one element (arr[i][j]) in a 2d bool array to True, all the j's set to True as well?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, boolean

I initialized a 2d array and set all the elements to `False`. Then in my code I want to switch certain elements to `True` if conditions are met. However, `arr[i][j] = True` sets ALL j elements in `arr` to `True`. Why is that, and what is the correct syntax?

```
arr = [[False]*3]*4
print(arr)
arr[1][2] = True
print(arr)
```

This gives

[[False, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]

which is what we expected, and then

[[False, False, True], [False, False, True], [False, False, True], [False, False, True]]

where all the arr[i][2]'s are set to True, instead of just arr[1][2]

Comment: Hi, the outer list contains 4 elements that are all the same instance, so modifying one will cause the other elements to reflect the change as well. `[False]*3` is a single list of 3 elements which is then inserted 4 times into the outer array.

Comment: Because he only modified the last element of the sublist - `arr[1][2] = True`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create multidimensional arrays with the `*` syntax. What happens is that `[False]*3` is evaluated first, creating a list with three elements that each refer to the immutable value `False`, but then the outer `[]*4` creates a list of four elements that all refer to the *same* three-element list. Instead, create an empty list, and use a loop to repeatedly append `[False]*3` to the list - that will reevaluate `[False]*3` every time, creating distinct inner lists.

Comment: The most compact one I know about is to use a comprehension: `[[False] * 3 for i in range(4)]`

Comment: Thank you!

and this applies to everything, lets say 
arr = [[1]*3]*4 as well, correct? Not just bool.

This should also be written as arr = [[1]*3 for _ in range(4)]?

didn't expect that, as arr = [1]*3 works fine

Comment: `[1] * 3` also creates three references to the _same_ `1`. But numbers are immutable. If they weren't, you'd see that changing one would change all. What you're changing when you do `arr[0] = 3` is not the number itself, but what the array's element 0 refers to.

Comment: `arr[0][0]` also changes what element 0 of the innermost array refers to (so the other elements in the inner array don't change), but all the elements of the outer array refer to the same inner array.